# Backbone.js destroy not passing model information to server?

Tags: backbone.js

My model definition:

```
var Note = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '/backbone/notes',

    defaults: function() {
      return {
        id: '',
        text: '',
        date: ''
      };
    },

    initialize: function() {
    },

});
```

I'm calling destroy on a model thusly:

```
    delete_note: function(e) {
        this.model.destroy({success: function(model) {
            console.log('success');
        }});            
    },
```

But if I look at the request in firebug it contains no information about the model so I don't know what to delete on the server side. My gets and puts work fine.

This is the model contents:

Object {text: "fdsasdfasdf", date: "Jun 14, 2013", id: 4685293923860480}

Any ideas?

Comment: can add your model definition?

Comment: Added the model definition. Am I supposed to add the id to the URL somehow, or is backbone supposed to be doing that on its own?

Comment: You might want to change model's url: to a urlRoot:

Comment: Changing it to urlRoot is what fixed it. Do you want to post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

The id of your model will be appended to the url when making requests to the server. So the Gets and Puts that are working should be going to:

```
/backbone/notes/4685293923860480
```

Delete should be going to the same URL, but should not include no information beyond that. You should have enough information on what to delete by the URL that was hit and the method that was used.